# connected weighted directed graph with diameter k< |V|, find the shortest path

Tags: algorithm, directed-graph

You are given a connected weighted directed graph G = (V,E) with diameter k < |V| and
I am trying to find a way to give the most efficient (running time) algorithm to find the shortest path from S (source) to any node v in V.
I cant figure it out how to use the given diameter to make the algorithm more efficient?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Have you considered [Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)?

Comment: Yes , I want to do it more efficient than |E| + |V|log|V|

Comment: Is the diameter k,  in nodes or weight?

Comment: Ah right - it isn't the most efficient algorithm for this task I don't think.

Comment: @sorin the diameter k in nodes

Comment: @OP It doesn't appear to seem like there are too many more efficient [options to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Directed_graphs_with_nonnegative_weights). Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah but you ignore the given diameter , how can we use the diameter for this task to make it more efficient?

Comment: Interesting question, I hope somebody knows the answer to this I'm very curious. I'm gonna let this one brew in my head for a bit and see if anything comes to fruition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diameter doesn't help at all, you can ignore it.
Take an extreme example, a fully connected graph. It's diameter will be 1 (every node is just one link away).

However you can imagine that all the edges have a very large weight except for a path like 1->2->3->4->5->..->N that have a very low weight, so the path will have to go through the low cost edges and therefore through all the nodes.

If the diameter is expressed in weight you can optimize dijkstra to ignore any update that grows over the diameter.

Comment: Thank you for that, I forgot to accept the answer, :)